# Why when we convert from supersaturated to saturated solution we must use the crystal of the same kind of solute?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Why when we convert from supersaturated to saturated solution we must use the crystal of the same kind of solute ?

Comment: Could you please add an example or elaborate more? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Says who?$\quad$

Comment: Basically crystallization is a problem of kinetics vs. thermodynamics. Basically a supersaturated solution is thermodynamically unstable. However due to kinetics it might take a nucleation center a very long time to form.

Answer (score 1):

Sodium acetate melts at 78°C, If you heat it to 80°C with one or two drops of water, you obtain a saturated solution of sodium acetate. You may cool it down, and you obtain a supersaturated solution at room temperature. The solution should crystallize, but it does not, because no molecule feels more inclined than the next one to start the first crystal. For the crystallization to occur, a small crystal of sodium acetate has to be dropped in the supersaturate solution. It act as a bait. As soon as this crystal touches the supersaturated solution, all the dissolved molecules rearranged themselves around this model and the whole solution is solidified in a couple of seconds. If the small crystal has a crystal structure which is very different from sodium acetate, no crystallization occurs. If the crystal structure is not very different from crystallized sodium acetate, the crystallization starts. Sometimes a dust grain is sufficient to start the crystallization.

Answer (score 0):

The question is,why, if we supersaturate solutions of sodium thiosulphate, sodium sulphate or sodium acetate, why we have to use the crystal of respective salt to start the rapid crystallization ?

We need not to. It is just the most natural and the most reliable way to set the crystallization centre.

Similar effect is achieved in sealed  pocked heaters by bending a chess from some metal alloy, forming crystallization centers at metal lattice irregularities.

Another way is strong shaking or involving other solid particles.